# Класс на php ( Многоязычность сайта )

Tags: phpmyadmin, классы, php, mysql

Помогите разобраться. Есть сессия, в которой сохраняется выбранный язык страницы.

Есть база с данными на трех языках (рус., ин., ит.), хочу написать центральный класс, который будет делать выбор из базы данных в зависимости от языка, который сохраняется в сессии.

Answer (score 1):

В который раз спрашиваю: а смысл изобретать велосипеды, когда все уже до вас [изобрели](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)?

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext):

> > gettext — библиотека проекта GNU для интернационализации, широко применяемая в свободном ПО.

Comment: я ничего не изобретаю, я стараюсь разобрать и понять, а еслиб хотел взять что-то готовое я бы вообще поставил какую-то цмс мультиязычную